# Need to run a Groundwater Analysis Based on Points to a Raster

Tags: raster, spatial-analyst

The title sounds daunting, but this task really isn't. I have well samples over a decade in certain locations through an area. These samples contain a value of that element at that point in time. I need to create a raster from these points to show the estimated dispersement in the area.

I know there is probably a lot of science behind this, but I need a quick and dirty way to do this. My background is much more in elevation in terms of raster, so I'm having an issue finding the right ArcGIS Tool for the job.

Here is the point's that I have, each colour representing a different range of values. It's also really important to note that only the latest sample is symbolized on the map when in fact there are four or five samples at each point that could have different values.
[image: Element Point Samples]

Like I said, I have a background in imagery / elevation when is comes to rasters. I needed a quick and dirty way to make this work, so I did a [Natural Neighbor (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000006p000000) Point to raster analysis. I think it worked decently:
[image: Natural Neighbor (Spatial Analyst)]

Really though I don't know. Does this tool fit the job or am I really stretching here?

Comment: I've always thought that with lower point densities, kriging or splining interpolators were the way to go. I'm sure that I read that somewhere but I can't recall where now. I suppose it really depends on the application though.